# Defining Multiple Proxy Endpoints

Tags: apigee

This is probably an unusual case as I'm trying to define a new Proxy Endpoint in an API Proxy.

Let's say I have a `default` Proxy Endpoint with a Conditional Flow to match `/myflow` and `action == GET` and that works fine.

then I defined a new Proxy Endpoint (`new_endpoint`) with its own Conditional Flow to match `/mynewflow` and `action == GET`.

`/mynewflow` works fine and goes to the `new_endpoint` as expected.

**however**

`/myflow` is *also* now going to `new_endpoint`! (i used the Trace tool and confirmed it).

Here is the HTTP Proxy Connection Settings for both:

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/v2</BasePath>
    <Properties/>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
<RouteRule name="default">
    <TargetEndpoint>default</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

Is this expected?  If it is, how do I make sure that `/myflow` routes to `default` Proxy Endpoint?

Comment: Can you add the condition for matching and the base path tags for both endpoints. This will help in answering this question.

Comment: @Srikanth you can add conditions on `HTTPProxyConnection`?  it's not mentioned in the docs...

Comment: Nope, conditions are only on route rules.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing your <RouteRule> in your proxy.  Just like the ConditionalFlow, you need a second RouteRule to point to your new target, which would look something like this:

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/v2</BasePath>
    <Properties/>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
<RouteRule name="new_endpoint">
    <TargetEndpoint>new_endpoint</TargetEndpoint>
    <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath "/mynewflow")</Condition>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="default">
    <TargetEndpoint>default</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

You don't need to include individual verbs, because we can assume everything to /mynewflow is going to go to the new_endpoint target.

Also, make sure you put the conditional RouteRule above the default RouteRule -- Apigee will match the first one so if default (no condition) is first, you will never match the condition on the remaining rules.

Comment: this i know...i've used this before...this dictates which *Target Endpoint* to go to.

Comment: Ah -- your code example was for a proxy to tell it which target endpoint to use.  As you seem to have already figured, you need a unique basepath to determine which proxy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I learned something today:  apparently it's `HttpProxyConnection/BasePath` dictates which Proxy Endpoint is selected

as soon as made sure that the `BasePath` is different for both endpoints, routing started the way I expected it to.

Comment: Does this mean you found the solution?